# Forge2DGame: No effect setting - body.position.setFrom(info.delta.game)

Tags: flame, forge2d

From this [example](https://github.com/flame-engine/flame_forge2d/blob/main/example/lib/draggable_sample.dart) you can drag around(not at the draggable point but some factor) a BodyComponent by setting `body.applyLinearImpulse`.

If I try to drag around, setting `body.position` I get no effect. I was hoping to be able to drag the BodyComponent around at the specific drag point.

Sample code line 37:

```
  @override
  bool onDragUpdate(DragUpdateInfo info) {
    // final worldDelta = Vector2(1, -1)..multiply(info.delta.game);
    // body.applyLinearImpulse(worldDelta * 1000);
    body.position.setFrom(info.delta.game);
    return false;
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should never manipulate `body.position` directly, since that could break the stability of the physics engine.

For your use-case you probably want to use a `MouseJoint` instead:

https://github.com/flame-engine/flame/blob/ba617790e4a7ca4dc03f4a2e29de43d42efd3482/packages/flame_forge2d/example/lib/mouse_joint_sample.dart

Comment: Thanks, do you know why the MouseJoint gets les and less "attached" after multiple drag, if you know what I mean. The example code is also doing it. Let me know I I should create a new question to elaborate.

Comment: Hmm, I don't think I see that effect in the example. Can you explain a bit more what you mean?

Comment: Yes, I will create a new question with an animation showing it...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71928016/mousejoint-gets-less-and-less-reactive